# Javascript help

Tags: javascript, html

Somewhere in this javascript, it is telling my webpage to put a space in between each menu item.
[alt text http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/5340/screenshot20100127at204.png](http://img85.imageshack.us/img85/5340/screenshot20100127at204.png)

**Here is the javascript:**

```
//** Chrome Drop Down Menu- Author: Dynamic Drive (http://www.dynamicdrive.com)

//** Updated: July 14th 06' to v2.0
    //1) Ability to "left", "center", or "right" align the menu items easily, just by modifying the CSS property "text-align".
    //2) Added an optional "swipe down" transitional effect for revealing the drop down menus.
    //3) Support for multiple Chrome menus on the same page.

//** Updated: Nov 14th 06' to v2.01- added iframe shim technique

//** Updated: July 23rd, 08 to v2.4
    //1) Main menu items now remain "selected" (CSS class "selected" applied) when user moves mouse into corresponding drop down menu. 
    //2) Adds ability to specify arbitrary HTML that gets added to the end of each menu item that carries a drop down menu (ie: a down arrow image).
    //3) All event handlers added to the menu are now unobstrusive, allowing you to define your own "onmouseover" or "onclick" events on the menu items.
    //4) Fixed elusive JS error in FF that sometimes occurs when mouse quickly moves between main menu items and drop down menus

//** Updated: Oct 29th, 08 to v2.5 (only .js file modified from v2.4)
    //1) Added ability to customize reveal animation speed (# of steps)
    //2) Menu now works in IE8 beta2 (a valid doctype at the top of the page is required)

var cssdropdown={
disappeardelay: 250, //set delay in miliseconds before menu disappears onmouseout
dropdownindicator: '', //specify full HTML to add to end of each menu item with a drop down menu
enablereveal: [true, 5], //enable swipe effect? [true/false, steps (Number of animation steps. Integer between 1-20. Smaller=faster)]
enableiframeshim: 1, //enable "iframe shim" in IE5.5 to IE7? (1=yes, 0=no)

//No need to edit beyond here////////////////////////

dropmenuobj: null, asscmenuitem: null, domsupport: document.all || document.getElementById, standardbody: null, iframeshimadded: false, revealtimers: {},

getposOffset:function(what, offsettype){
    var totaloffset=(offsettype=="left")? what.offsetLeft : what.offsetTop;
    var parentEl=what.offsetParent;
    while (parentEl!=null){
        totaloffset=(offsettype=="left")? totaloffset+parentEl.offsetLeft : totaloffset+parentEl.offsetTop;
        parentEl=parentEl.offsetParent;
    }
    return totaloffset;
},

css:function(el, targetclass, action){
    var needle=new RegExp("(^|\\s+)"+targetclass+"($|\\s+)", "ig")
    if (action=="check")
        return needle.test(el.className)
    else if (action=="remove")
        el.className=el.className.replace(needle, "")
    else if (action=="add" && !needle.test(el.className))
        el.className+=" "+targetclass
},

showmenu:function(dropmenu, e){
    if (this.enablereveal[0]){
        if (!dropmenu._trueheight || dropmenu._trueheight<10)
            dropmenu._trueheight=dropmenu.offsetHeight
        clearTimeout(this.revealtimers[dropmenu.id])
        dropmenu.style.height=dropmenu._curheight=0
        dropmenu.style.overflow="hidden"
        dropmenu.style.visibility="visible"
        this.revealtimers[dropmenu.id]=setInterval(function(){cssdropdown.revealmenu(dropmenu)}, 10)
    }
    else{
        dropmenu.style.visibility="visible"
    }
    this.css(this.asscmenuitem, "selected", "add")
},

revealmenu:function(dropmenu, dir){
    var curH=dropmenu._curheight, maxH=dropmenu._trueheight, steps=this.enablereveal[1]
    if (curH<maxH){
        var newH=Math.min(curH, maxH)
        dropmenu.style.height=newH+"px"
        dropmenu._curheight= newH + Math.round((maxH-newH)/steps) + 1
    }
    else{ //if done revealing menu
        dropmenu.style.height="auto"
        dropmenu.style.overflow="hidden"
        clearInterval(this.revealtimers[dropmenu.id])
    }
},

clearbrowseredge:function(obj, whichedge){
    var edgeoffset=0
    if (whichedge=="rightedge"){
        var windowedge=document.all && !window.opera? this.standardbody.scrollLeft+this.standardbody.clientWidth-15 : window.pageXOffset+window.innerWidth-15
        var dropmenuW=this.dropmenuobj.offsetWidth
        if (windowedge-this.dropmenuobj.x < dropmenuW)  //move menu to the left?
            edgeoffset=dropmenuW-obj.offsetWidth
    }
    else{
        var topedge=document.all && !window.opera? this.standardbody.scrollTop : window.pageYOffset
        var windowedge=document.all && !window.opera? this.standardbody.scrollTop+this.standardbody.clientHeight-15 : window.pageYOffset+window.innerHeight-18
        var dropmenuH=this.dropmenuobj._trueheight
        if (windowedge-this.dropmenuobj.y < dropmenuH){ //move up?
            edgeoffset=dropmenuH+obj.offsetHeight
            if ((this.dropmenuobj.y-topedge)<dropmenuH) //up no good either?
                edgeoffset=this.dropmenuobj.y+obj.offsetHeight-topedge
        }
    }
    return edgeoffset
},

dropit:function(obj, e, dropmenuID){
    if (this.dropmenuobj!=null) //hide previous menu
        this.hidemenu() //hide menu
    this.clearhidemenu()
    this.dropmenuobj=document.getElementById(dropmenuID) //reference drop down menu
    this.asscmenuitem=obj //reference associated menu item
    this.showmenu(this.dropmenuobj, e)
    this.dropmenuobj.x=this.getposOffset(obj, "left")
    this.dropmenuobj.y=this.getposOffset(obj, "top")
    this.dropmenuobj.style.left=this.dropmenuobj.x-this.clearbrowseredge(obj, "rightedge")+"px"
    this.dropmenuobj.style.top=this.dropmenuobj.y-this.clearbrowseredge(obj, "bottomedge")+obj.offsetHeight+1+"px"
    this.positionshim() //call iframe shim function
},

positionshim:function(){ //display iframe shim function
    if (this.iframeshimadded){
        if (this.dropmenuobj.style.visibility=="visible"){
            this.shimobject.style.width=this.dropmenuobj.offsetWidth+"px"
            this.shimobject.style.height=this.dropmenuobj._trueheight+"px"
            this.shimobject.style.left=parseInt(this.dropmenuobj.style.left)+"px"
            this.shimobject.style.top=parseInt(this.dropmenuobj.style.top)+"px"
            this.shimobject.style.display="block"
        }
    }
},

hideshim:function(){
    if (this.iframeshimadded)
        this.shimobject.style.display='none'
},

isContained:function(m, e){
    var e=window.event || e
    var c=e.relatedTarget || ((e.type=="mouseover")? e.fromElement : e.toElement)
    while (c && c!=m)try {c=c.parentNode} catch(e){c=m}
    if (c==m)
        return true
    else
        return false
},

dynamichide:function(m, e){
    if (!this.isContained(m, e)){
        this.delayhidemenu()
    }
},

delayhidemenu:function(){
    this.delayhide=setTimeout("cssdropdown.hidemenu()", this.disappeardelay) //hide menu
},

hidemenu:function(){
    this.css(this.asscmenuitem, "selected", "remove")
    this.dropmenuobj.style.visibility='hidden'
    this.dropmenuobj.style.left=this.dropmenuobj.style.top="-1000px"
    this.hideshim()
},

clearhidemenu:function(){
    if (this.delayhide!="undefined")
        clearTimeout(this.delayhide)
},

addEvent:function(target, functionref, tasktype){
    if (target.addEventListener)
        target.addEventListener(tasktype, functionref, false);
    else if (target.attachEvent)
        target.attachEvent('on'+tasktype, function(){return functionref.call(target, window.event)});
},

startchrome:function(){
    if (!this.domsupport)
        return
    this.standardbody=(document.compatMode=="CSS1Compat")? document.documentElement : document.body
    for (var ids=0; ids<arguments.length; ids++){
        var menuitems=document.getElementById(arguments[ids]).getElementsByTagName("a")
        for (var i=0; i<menuitems.length; i++){
            if (menuitems[i].getAttribute("rel")){
                var relvalue=menuitems[i].getAttribute("rel")
                var asscdropdownmenu=document.getElementById(relvalue)
                this.addEvent(asscdropdownmenu, function(){cssdropdown.clearhidemenu()}, "mouseover")
                this.addEvent(asscdropdownmenu, function(e){cssdropdown.dynamichide(this, e)}, "mouseout")
                this.addEvent(asscdropdownmenu, function(){cssdropdown.delayhidemenu()}, "click")
                try{
                    menuitems[i].innerHTML=menuitems[i].innerHTML+" "+this.dropdownindicator
                }catch(e){}
                this.addEvent(menuitems[i], function(e){ //show drop down menu when main menu items are mouse over-ed
                    if (!cssdropdown.isContained(this, e)){
                        var evtobj=window.event || e
                        cssdropdown.dropit(this, evtobj, this.getAttribute("rel"))
                    }
                }, "mouseover")
                this.addEvent(menuitems[i], function(e){cssdropdown.dynamichide(this, e)}, "mouseout") //hide drop down menu when main menu items are mouse out
                this.addEvent(menuitems[i], function(){cssdropdown.delayhidemenu()}, "click") //hide drop down menu when main menu items are clicked on
            }
        } //end inner for
    } //end outer for
    if (this.enableiframeshim && document.all && !window.XDomainRequest && !this.iframeshimadded){ //enable iframe shim in IE5.5 thru IE7?
        document.write('<IFRAME id="iframeshim" src="about:blank" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no" style="left:0; top:0; position:absolute; display:none;z-index:90; background: transparent;"></IFRAME>')
        this.shimobject=document.getElementById("iframeshim") //reference iframe object
        this.shimobject.style.filter='progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(style=0,opacity=0)'
        this.iframeshimadded=true
    }
} //end startchrome

}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please in this case, don't dump the full script here, it is simply too large. Please link to the source page where you got it from (somewhere on Dynamic Drive, I suppose).

Comment: Assuming that the code is not supposed to generate a menu that looks like that the problem is probably in your css, not your javascript.  Could you format the relevant part of your javascript with the code button (101010) and add the css this script included (if any)?

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, I'd likely expect that it's your CSS, not the javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting each of those elements to `display:block` and `float:left`. That will remove the gaps.

Comment: can you please show me an example of how I can apply that to this javascript code?